# How in Swift do I iterate over all FourCharCode table tags for a loaded, OpenType font?

Tags: swift, tags, core-text, opentype

This may be just an `UnsafeRawPointer` question, but I don't quite know.

In my Swift-based app, I have loaded an OpenType/TrueType font into a CoreText font object.

I then ask for an array for all of the font's table tags, each of which is a `FourCharCode` (`UInt32`), where each byte is a printable ASCII character, in big-endian order.  The answer from CoreText is a `CFArray`, which I want to iterate over, like this:

```swift
allTableTags = CTFontCopyAvailableTables(theFont!, CTFontTableOptions(rawValue: 0))
guard allTableTags != nil else { return }

let numTags = CFArrayGetCount(allTableTags)     // 13
for i in 0..<numTags {
  let tagPtr = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allTableTags, i) // UnsafeRawPointer?
  if tagPtr != nil {
    let tag = tagPtr!.load(as: FourCharCode.self) // Crashes here
    let str = Utility.tagToString(tag)
    debugPrint("tag: \(str)")
  }
}
```

But it crashes when I try to read the pointer as a 4-byte integer.  Where is this going wrong?

Comment: Avoid all of that "CF" stuff. Try casting the result to a Swift array: `let allTableTags = CTFontCopyAvailableTables(theFont!, CTFontTableOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? [CTFontTableTag]`. Then you can iterate the tags like a normal Swift array.

Comment: Your suggestion instantly crashes.  And Apple's documentation on this stuff is terrible (or I'd know what to do).

Comment: Is the crash from the cast or the call to `CTFontCopyAvailableTables`?

Answer (score 0):

The array values in `allTableTags[]` are not pointers, they are the actual 4-byte tags stored as eight-byte values (each taking up the same space as a pointer).

Apple's `CoreText` documentation doesn't explain this in any satisfactory way that I can discern.  Contrary to its declaration in the official header, in this `CoreText` case, `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex()` does not always return a `UnsafeRawPointer?`.

So instead of

```
let tag = tagPtr!.load(as: FourCharCode.self)
```

use this:

```
let tag = CTFontTableTag( Int(bitPattern: tagPtr) )
```

This also means you don't have to check for the returned array value being a nil pointer, which in a legal font would never happen anyway.  It's not a pointer.  So the final Swift code would be:

```
let allTags = CTFontCopyAvailableTables(theFont!, CTFontTableOptions(rawValue: 0))
guard allTags != nil else { return }

let numTags = CFArrayGetCount(allTags)
for i in 0..<numTags {
    let notPtr = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allTags, i)          // Not an UnsafeRawPointer?
    let tag = CTFontTableTag( Int(bitPattern: notPtr) )      // Get low-order 4 bytes
    Swift.print("\(Utility.tagToString(tag))")
    }
```

For one particular NSFont in `theFont` with 13 tables, the result of running the above is:

```
CFF 
DSIG
GDEF
GPOS
GSUB
OS/2
cmap
head
hhea
hmtx
maxp
name
post
```

So it's plainly working, as these are standard four-ASCII-byte OpenType/TrueType font table tags.  The only remaining issue I can't test is whether these tags can be big- or little-endian.  The tagToString() utility I wrote and used above is assuming big-ending integer four-byte tags.